# Activity not starting, another activity is starting instead

Tags: android

I am facing a very weird issue. I am trying to launch one activity but instead of that, another activity is opening. I am trying to open RegActivity, I do have specified it in manifest and also made it Launcher activity but instead of that when I run the app "MainActivity" is calling.

MainActivity is not even a Launcher or Default activity. I cleaned up the project, Rebuilt it. But still, nothing works.

**My Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.solodroid.ecommerce" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="Frizzy"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme2" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.solodroid.ecommerce.RegActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.solodroid.ecommerce.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.solodroid.ecommerce.ActivityCategoryList"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.solodroid.ecommerce.ActivityMenuList"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.solodroid.ecommerce.ActivityMenuDetail"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.solodroid.ecommerce.ActivityCart"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.solodroid.ecommerce.ActivityCheckout"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.solodroid.ecommerce.ActivityConfirmMessage"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.solodroid.ecommerce.ActivityContactUs"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.solodroid.ecommerce.ActivityProfile"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.solodroid.ecommerce.ActivityInformation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.solodroid.ecommerce.ActivityAbout"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.solodroid.ecommerce.LoginActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>

        <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" 
               />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**RegActivity.java**

```
package com.solodroid.ecommerce;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONException;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class RegActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText etid, etname, etstorename, etemail, etphone, etdoj;
    Button btnregister;
    TextView tvlogin;
    private ParseContent parseContent;
    PreferenceHelper preferenceHelper;
    private final int RegTask = 1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_reg);

        preferenceHelper = new PreferenceHelper(this);
        parseContent = new ParseContent(this);

        if(preferenceHelper.getIsLogin()){
            Intent intent = new Intent(RegActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            this.finish();
        }

        //etid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etmi_id);
        etname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etname);
        //etstorename = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etstore_name);
        etemail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etemail);
        etphone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etphone);
       // etdoj = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etdoj);
        btnregister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        tvlogin = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvlogin);

        tvlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(RegActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        btnregister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    register();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private void register() throws IOException, JSONException {

        if (!AndyUtils.isNetworkAvailable(RegActivity.this)) {
            Toast.makeText(RegActivity.this, "Internet is required!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        AndyUtils.showSimpleProgressDialog(RegActivity.this);
        final HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
       // map.put(AndyConstants.Params.MI_ID, etid.getText().toString());
        map.put(AndyConstants.Params.NAME, etname.getText().toString());
       // map.put(AndyConstants.Params.STORE_NAME, etstorename.getText().toString());
        map.put(AndyConstants.Params.EMAIL, etemail.getText().toString());
        map.put(AndyConstants.Params.PHONE, etphone.getText().toString());
        //map.put(AndyConstants.Params.DOJ, etdoj.getText().toString());
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>(){
            protected String doInBackground(Void[] params) {
                String response="";
                try {
                    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest(AndyConstants.ServiceType.REGISTER);
                    response = req.prepare(HttpRequest.Method.POST).withData(map).sendAndReadString();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    response=e.getMessage();
                }
                return response;
            }
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                //do something with response
                Log.d("newwwss", result);
                onTaskCompleted(result, RegTask);
            }
        }.execute();
    }

    private void onTaskCompleted(String response,int task) {
        Log.d("responsejson", response.toString());
        AndyUtils.removeSimpleProgressDialog();  //will remove progress dialog
        switch (task) {
            case RegTask:

                if (parseContent.isSuccess(response)) {

                    parseContent.saveInfo(response);
                    Toast.makeText(RegActivity.this, "Registered Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(RegActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    this.finish();

                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(RegActivity.this, parseContent.getErrorMessage(response), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
        }
    }
}
```

**LoginActivity.java**

```
package com.solodroid.ecommerce;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONException;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText etemail, etpassword;
     Button btnlogin;
     TextView tvreg;
    private ParseContent parseContent;
    private final int LoginTask = 1;
     PreferenceHelper preferenceHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        parseContent = new ParseContent(this);
        preferenceHelper = new PreferenceHelper(this);

        etemail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etusername);
        etpassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etpassword);
        btnlogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        tvreg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvreg);

        tvreg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        btnlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    login();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void login() throws IOException, JSONException {

        if (!AndyUtils.isNetworkAvailable(LoginActivity.this)) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Internet is required!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        AndyUtils.showSimpleProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
        final HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(AndyConstants.Params.EMAIL, etemail.getText().toString());
        map.put(AndyConstants.Params.PASSWORD, etpassword.getText().toString());
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>(){
            protected String doInBackground(Void[] params) {
                String response="";
                try {
                    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest(AndyConstants.ServiceType.LOGIN);
                    response = req.prepare(HttpRequest.Method.POST).withData(map).sendAndReadString();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    response=e.getMessage();
                }
                return response;
            }
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                //do something with response
                Log.d("newwwss", result);
                onTaskCompleted(result,LoginTask);
            }
        }.execute();
    }

    private void onTaskCompleted(String response, int task) {
        Log.d("responsejson", response.toString());
        AndyUtils.removeSimpleProgressDialog();  //will remove progress dialog
        switch (task) {
            case LoginTask:
                if (parseContent.isSuccess(response)) {
                    parseContent.saveInfo(response);
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,RegActivity.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    this.finish();
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, parseContent.getErrorMessage(response), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
        }
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.solodroid.ecommerce;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseAnalytics;
import com.parse.ParseInstallation;
import com.parse.PushService;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private AdapterNavDrawerList adapter;

    // declare dbhelper and adapter object
    static DBHelper dbhelper;
    AdapterMainMenu mma;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.nav_drawer_main);

        // Parse push notification
        Parse.initialize(this, getString(R.string.parse_application_id), getString(R.string.parse_client_key));
        ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());
        PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MainActivity.class);
        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.navigation_drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));

        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));

        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[6], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(6, -1)));

        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[7], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(7, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[8], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(8, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[9], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(9, -1)));

        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new AdapterNavDrawerList(getApplicationContext(), navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
        bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.header)));

        // get screen device width and height
        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

        // checking internet connection
        if (!Constant.isNetworkAvailable(MainActivity.this)) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, getString(R.string.no_internet), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        mma = new AdapterMainMenu(this);
        dbhelper = new DBHelper(this);

        // create database
        try {
            dbhelper.createDataBase();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            throw new Error("Unable to create database");
        }

        // then, the database will be open to use
        try {
            dbhelper.openDataBase();
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            throw sqle;
        }

        // if user has already ordered food previously then show confirm dialog
        if (dbhelper.isPreviousDataExist()) {
            showAlertDialog();
        }

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer, // nav
                                                                                                // menu
                                                                                                // toggle
                                                                                                // icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for
                                    // accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for
                                    // accessibility
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }
    }

    // show confirm dialog to ask user to delete previous order or not
    void showAlertDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.confirm);
        builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.db_exist_alert));
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.yes), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // delete order data when yes button clicked
                dbhelper.deleteAllData();
                dbhelper.close();

            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.no), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // close dialog when no button clicked
                dbhelper.close();
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        dbhelper.deleteAllData();
        dbhelper.close();
        finish();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.open_main, R.anim.close_next);
    }

    /**
     * Slide menu item click listener
     */
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.rate_app:
            try {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + getPackageName())));
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + getPackageName())));
            }
            return true;
        case R.id.more_app:
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(getString(R.string.more_apps))));
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /*
     * * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.ic_menu).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     */
    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new ActivityHome();
            break;
        case 1:
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityCategoryList.class));
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.open_next, R.anim.close_next);
            break;
        case 2:
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityCart.class));
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.open_next, R.anim.close_next);
            break;
        case 3:
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityCheckout.class));
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.open_next, R.anim.close_next);
            break;
        case 4:
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityProfile.class));
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.open_next, R.anim.close_next);
            break;
        case 5:
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityInformation.class));
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.open_next, R.anim.close_next);
            break;
        case 6:
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityAbout.class));
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.open_next, R.anim.close_next);

            break;
        case 7:
            Intent sendInt = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendInt.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getString(R.string.app_name));
            sendInt.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "E-Commerce Android App\n\"" + getString(R.string.app_name)
                    + "\" \nhttps://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + getPackageName());
            sendInt.setType("text/plain");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendInt, "Share"));
            break;
        case 8:
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityContactUs.class));
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.open_next, R.anim.close_next);

            break;
        case 9:
            dbhelper.deleteAllData();
            dbhelper.close();
            MainActivity.this.finish();
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.open_next, R.anim.close_next);

            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

}
```

What is wrong here? I don't find anything.

Comment: Looks like `preferenceHelper.getIsLogin()` always returns true. If this isn't the case and you still need help, please add more code so others can reproduce the error.

Comment: @0X0nosugar   please check the edited code

Comment: Comment out MainActivity in your manifest. That way when you run your app and the activity tried to open, you will get an activity not found exception which will indicate where in your code the activity is launching from.

Comment: @Kuffs: It is now showing the same exception as you mentioned. Plus indicating problem is in preferncehelper.isLogin().

Comment: @Kuffs: But, I don't understand this. how can isLogin wrong? this is totally right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this code in your onCreate()

```
if(preferenceHelper.getIsLogin()){
            Intent intent = new Intent(RegActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            this.finish();
        }
```

if `preferenceHelper.getIsLogin()` is true you wont be able to see your RegActivity beacause it will instantly start MainActivity.

Comment: you mean i should exclude it?

Comment: Yes try Excluding for testing or try using `if(!preferenceHelper.getIsLogin())`